# Get location data from device in page load

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the javascript from [Praytimes.org](http://praytimes.org/code/git/?a=tree&p=PrayTimes&hb=HEAD&f=v2/js)
and i want to get the location data from device during loading the page and pass it as **lat and long** 
as below

```js
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [lat,long], +6);
```

The sample page is as fol.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Daily Prayer Timetable </title>
 <style>
  body, td, th {font-family: verdana; font-size: 12px; color: #404040;}
  #timetable {border-width: 1px; border-style: outset; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: gray; width: 9em;}
  #timetable td, #timetable th {border-width: 1px; border-spacing: 1px; padding: 2px 4px; border-style: inset; border-color: #CCCCCC;}
  #timetable th {color:black; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background-color: #F8F7F4;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../PrayTimes.js"></script>

<br>
<p align="center">Jessore,Bangladesh<p>
<div align="center" id="table"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var date = new Date(); // today
 var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [lat,long], +6);
 var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha', 'Midnight'];

 var html = '<table id="timetable">';
 html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</th></tr>';
 for(var i in list) {
  html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
  html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
 }
 html += '</table>';
 document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A short demo

```js
var latitude, longitude; // keep a variable to store lat, long for future use
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showCoordinate);

function showCoordinate(rawPosition){
    latitude = rawPosition.coords.latitute;
    longitude = rawPosition.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: thank you. i tried the same. but here the  geolocation script runs only. the PrayTimes.js doesn't run at all

Comment: what do you mean? praytimes.js is not supposed to run and show anything. it's an api

Comment: sorry, i couldnt make it clear in my words. i want to get the geolocation data at first , preferably when the page loads, then i want to pass the lat,lon to the //prayTimes.getTimes(date, [lat,long], +6); method. so that the getTimes method returns me the times. 
here when i add the script for geolocation , it runs only the geolocation script and not the other script to get the times